# Magento devbox not install

Tags: magento2, docker

I install magento devbox based on docker on windows10pro. And get error

> ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: invalid bind
>   mount spec
>   "C:\magedevbox\shared\logs\php-fpm:/var/log/php-fpm:rw": invalid
>   volume specification:
>   'C:\magedevbox\shared\logs\php-fpm:/var/log/php-fpm:rw'
>
> ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid bind
>   mount spec
>   "C:\magedevbox\shared\var\logs\mysql:/var/log/mysql:rw": invalid
>   volume specification:
>   'C:\magedevbox\shared\var\logs\mysql:/var/log/mysql:rw'
>   [31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
>   ERROR: No container found for web_1
>
> Install Magento
>
> [31mERROR[0m: No container found for web_1

Answer (score 2):

you need to create file `.env` with following content

`COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` and put that file next to docker-compose.yml

Note : file without name is not possible to make in windows GUI so use command prompt to `create file ()`